Getting auth error while loading widget in updated iOS and macOS devices
screenshot
While testing on new devices we found out that the Banno widget(iframe) is giving us an authorization error on newer versions of iOS(iOS 18) and macOS(macOS Sequoia 15.0).
It happens only for browsers and not for the Garden FI app.
On previous versions of the respective devices it also works well for both browser and app.
Is it something Banno specific that is causing the issue?
Please let me know if anything more info is needed.

I'm looking into this - thanks for the screenshot! If possible, could you use the https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example and provide steps to reproduce this error (if it still occurs) using the example plugin.

So if you configure and run the example plugin and load the Garden FI in updated iOS or macOS browser, you should be able to get the error.

Is it possible that you post a minimal reproducible code ? That may help pinpoint issue on how you embedded the iframe.

@DevilishSpirits everything you need is in this repo link You can reproduce the issue using this code.

I wasn't able to recreate the error exactly as described, but experienced something similar in Safari. The issue I encountered was related to using http (insecure) for localhost development, Safari security settings were causing the issues. Maybe worth looking into that.

HTTP should not be an issue, our QA/UAT env uses secure https connections and even there we were able to get the issue. Did you try the above on updated versions of the devices mentioned in query.

Not sure if it helps but the issue is also observed on chrome browser. Also one of the default cards(Credit Score) in Garden FI is showing the same issue on load.

We too are facing this issue. The issue seems to be specific to Safari 18, both on macOS 15 and iOS 18 as described here

We've been able to reproduce this - still looking into the details, however.

Might be an issue with Apple's code: https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/762983
